# Regular expression for a single letter word

Tags: java, regex

I use Java for an app with a stream of strings input. I want a regex that could detect whether there is a single-letter *word* "C/c", but not just a letter "C/c" in a longer.

For instance:

- "I like C." -> true
- "I like Canada." -> false
- "C." -> true
- "I like C and C++." -> true

I think this pattern should be like "`*c*`", the former `*` should not be letter, the latter `*` should be one of `, .; )!` or space.

I just get confused with the regex. I tried some pattern pattern like `[^A-Za-z]{0,}c[\,\.\;\s]{0,}`, but it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 4):

Use word boundary markers

```
String pattern = ".*\\b[Cc]\\b.*";
```

The `\b` matches a word boundary, i.e., anything of letter next to non-letter.

You need the 2 backslashes to escape the backslash for Java.

The `.*` in the beginning and end make sure that Java does not try to anchor the pattern at beginning and end of the input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.This is really helpful. But for furthure requirement,which I didn't stated, like syntax checking. for  instance, c-- would be no valid. So I revised the latter "b.*". And I notice the very first ".*" could be removed.   
The final example is here:  https://regex101.com/r/C7XICk/1

Answer (score 1):

Use `\W`. `\W`is non-word character.

```
\W[cC]\W
```

https://regex101.com/r/khvMQk/1

Comment: So thanks for the regex website. It is really helpful to test. And just to revise it better, here is the final outcome:https://regex101.com/r/C7XICk/1

Answer (score 0):

Try his

var pattern=   /(\bC\b)/i;

https://regex101.com/r/gN5Z8Q/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The pattern your gave is quite ok except for single statement ,like "c". Check this:https://regex101.com/r/5uUXkE/1

And this is what I revised,https://regex101.com/r/C7XICk/1. Anyway, thanks for your answer.